# How to combine template and attribute based routing in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to define template based routing to controller and then attribute based for actions in ASP.NET Core. Something like:

```
public class Foo : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public object Get()
    {
        return new
        {
            ID = "A"
        };
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public object Create([FromBody]dynamic entity)
    {
        return new
        {
            ID = "B"
        };
    }


}
```

Route

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute("Settings", "settings/api/foo",
                    new { controller = "Foo" }
            );
        });
```

And I expect this to work:

```
GET /settings/api/foo
POST /settings/api/foo
```

Unfortunately it is not a case. It looks like route attributes are ignored. What is the best way to achieve requirement?

Comment: Are you getting 404 for both GET and POST ?

Comment: Those (`[HttpPost]` & `[HttpGet]`) are not route attributes, they are HTTP Method attributes. Route attributes look like `[Route("settings/api/foo")]`

Comment: @danludwig they are IRouteTemplateProvider so they are route attributes

Comment: @Shyju yep, I can use hack with method restriction in route, but this is x4 mappings for each controller and I want to avoid this

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read this as a core 1.0 question.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to route the URL to a specific controller *and* action. Then use action method *overloading* with an action method selector to switch between the GET and POST.

Change your route setup code to this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Settings",
        "settings/api/foo",
        new {
            controller = "Foo", // specific controller
            action = "DoThing", // AND specific action
        }
    );
});
```

And change the controller to have both action methods (or however many you want - one for each HTTP verb) to have the *same name*, but using different action methods selectors:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet] // different action method selector!
    public object DoThing() // same name!
    {
        return new
        {
            ID = "A"
        };
    }

    [HttpPost] // different action method selector!
    public object DoThing([FromBody]dynamic entity) // same name!
    {
        return new
        {
            ID = "B"
        };
    }
}
```

This way MVC will route all the requests for that URL to an action called `DoThing` on controller `Foo`. Once it gets there it sees "oh my, oh my, there are two actions with the same name!" But then it sees the `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` action method selectors, and whichever one of them says it can handle the request will win.

Comment: My fault that I tried to simplify code to show problem. This is not going to work with HttpGet("{id}"), HttpDelete("{id}"). So question is still the same, how to route to controller using template based routing and then make attribute routes work.